# prototype.js equivalent of jquery .after()

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, jquery-after

What is the prototype.js equivalent of following code

```
jQuery('#txtId').after(divdata);
```

Comment: do you mean javascript equivalvent???

Comment: @gov he means prototype js, not the vanila js one. ;)

Comment: @regel i always hear vanila js , what does that mean??

Comment: @gov: plain javascript, without a framework/library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/insert

well you use insert look at the link above

```
 $('selector').insert ({'after': 'Content'});
```

in your case it would look like this

```
$('#txtId').insert ({'after':divdata});
```

Comment: sorry but i just realized that i am on 1.5 any ways thanks for the help +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

Are looking for this,

```
new Insertion.After('id of element', "HTML");
```

[`Ref`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/insertion/after)

Comment: Insertion is deprecated any other solution

Answer (score 0):

Dies this work? I dont think there is a shortcut like after in jquery.

```
$(selector).each(function(){
   appendChild(document.createTextNode("Text or html to insert"));
 });
```